# Why I am not getting the identity matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Hello I am trying to understant why after this operation:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
ainv = inv(a)
print(np.dot(a,ainv))
```

I am getting:

```
[[1.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00]
 [8.8817842e-16 1.0000000e+00]]
```

Since I am using the a's inverse matrix I think that I shoud get:

```
[[1,0],[0,1]]
```

SO I would like support to understand the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = np.array([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]) 
ainv = np.linalg.inv(a)  #[[-2.0, 1.0],[1.5, -0.5]]
print(np.dot(a,ainv))
```

Yields as you discovered:

```
[[1.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00]
 [8.8817842e-16 1.0000000e+00]]
```

Lets look at the type of the array elements

```
type(ainv[1][1])
```

Shows us that the type of the array is

```
numpy.float64
```

Lets look at the numpy precision  for this type

```
numpy.finfo(numpy.float64).precision
```

Numpy says the aproximate number of decimal digits to which this kind of float is precise is 15.

```
15
```

For curiosity, we can also look at the machine epsilon for the type;

```
np.finfo(np.float64).eps
```

Which yields the smallest number n where 1 +n is indistinguishable from 1

```
2.220446049250313e-16
```

So even though the number you get is technically distinguishable from 0 for the datatype, the overall precision is 15 decimals, calculations on large matrices might compound floating point imprecision  even further.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the complete explanation

Answer (score 1):

That is the identity matrix, almost.  You are getting numbers very close to zero instead of zero, which is a common issue with floating point numbers since they are only a finite approximation of real numbers.  For all practical purposes 8.8e-16 or 0.00000000000000088 is ~ zero.